# Building two images passing different build-arg to the same image

Tags: docker

I need to publish two Docker images using the same Dockerfile, passing at build time a different argument.

I understand I can do something like

```
docker build --build-arg TIMEZONE='Europe/Rome' -t image-cet .
docker tag image-cet docker.pkg.github.com/user/registry/image-CET
docker push docker.pkg.github.com/user/registry/image-CET

docker build --build-arg TIMEZONE='Europe/Bucharest' -t image-eet .
docker tag image-eet docker.pkg.github.com/user/registry/image-EET
docker push docker.pkg.github.com/user/registry/image-EET
```

However, this will double the build time. Is there a way to first build the image without TIMEZONE (let's call it base) and then build the two images from the base passing the timezone?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Dockerfile, there are multiple options.

Option 1: Use multi stage build. Place all of your commands which are independent of the `ARG` to the first stage, then use that as 'base' for your second stage which will make use of the `TIMEZONE`. Refer to [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds).

Option 2: Place your `ARG TIMEZONE` command to the last possible line of your Dockerfile (last line before it's actually used). This will enable as much layers to remain independent of the arg, which both images will use from build cache.

Option 3: Maybe your `ARG` can instead be an environment variable. If you aren't using it during the build process, that is `RUN` commands, you can pass it as an environment variable at the end of the Dockerfile or when you start the container.